# Square of a p-adic number is an integer.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is a question for an assignment, so just some pointers in the right direction would be great.

Suppose that $n \in \mathbb Z$ and that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q_p$ satisfies $\alpha^2 = n$. Prove that $\alpha$ must be a $p$-adic integer.

So far I have that if $\alpha = \sum_{k=-r}^{\infty} a_kp^k$ then
$$
\alpha^2 = a_{-r}p^{-2r} + 2a_{-r}a_{-r+1}p^{-2r+1} + \cdots
$$
 But how can I conclude that if this is an integer then $a_i = 0$ for all negative $i$?

Comment: Hint: Compute $|\alpha|_p$.

Comment: Oh wow, that was really simple. I was clearly overthinking it, thanks.

Comment: you are welcome.